# How to control RGB on a headless server running Arch?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, rgb

I'm repurposing some gaming components as a headless server running Arch Linux. I'd like to control the extensive RGB lighting via software. I found openrgb, but the AUR package depends on wayland, qt... are there any true headless alternatives?

Comment: To know what you are trying to accomplish: You've got an old gaming PC with RGB LEDs mounted on its case or even inside it, which then start emit light in various colors when the machine is running, right?

Comment: It is open source software. It could be possible to remove the GUI. Because it’s Linux we’re talking about, a headless X Server or Wayland Compositor could also be used.

Comment: @Neppomuk precisely

Comment: @DanielB I know, but before unnecessarily running a display server or forking the project, I'd like to know if there is an existing way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer in this section of the OpenRGB FAQ: [Can I set up OpenRGB as a systemd service?](https://gitlab.com/OpenRGBDevelopers/OpenRGB-Wiki/-/blob/stable/Frequently-Asked-Questions.md#can-i-set-up-openrgb-as-a-systemd-service)

Services typically run in the background and are therefore not connected to a terminal. It will still require some GUI libraries when being run as a service, though.